# Cloud app for desktop with the ability to make screenshots

Tags: screenshot, cloud-storage

Can anyone suggest a Cloud app with the desktop client which is able to conveniently made screenshots of the full screen and its part and save those screenshots to the Cloud automatically? With at least 15Gb space. It should be available for Windows and Android. It should be free. It is better for me to have an app without ads, but if ad will be I will put up with it. I would like it to take screenshot because of me clicking buttons. I want to be able to configure buttons I want to click in order to take the screenshot. I am from Ukraine and Mail.ru cloud is blocked here. It had all the requirements I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly is required. But I'm using Greenshot to take screenshots of a full screen or a region on the screen. And there is an Imgur plugin that allows you to quickly upload screenshots to the interwebs.

Also Dropbox has a capability of taking screenshots, but I've never used it - another option for you to check out.

Answer (score 0):

I can not recommend Sharex enough for this application, it's seamless, works amazingly and you can decide where to upload.

I use it with my imgur account and let the images be uploaded to private.